# can one create a custom linux install from a configuration?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, mint

I usually like to install a few things on my machine directly after install. Then do some general tasks like set the preferences, make a conkyrc, set up my git config, download my pictures, etc.

Is it possible to make this all done directly from install? As in, to write this as an install image so it would configure it automatically on install

Comment: Yes but it is far from easy: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: That comment Q is basically "How do I make my own Ubuntu-based distro" I think, I'll bet several distros do exactly that. I think there's  an easier way to set up a few things right after installing normally, but it's not a one-click-install, I'll post it

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading "from a configuration" as in "from a configuration right after installing" so this sounds pretty close:

I use a bash script to set up some general items after installing (I usually run a live usb so every boot is like a fresh install), the script copies config files to $HOME & /etc & other places (software repos, etc), installs a few programs (pre-downloaded .deb's or could `apt-get update && apt-get install ...`) and log out & log in (easiest way to "reset" desktop settings).

You can do that by adding the script & files to another drive, another partition, even online somewhere, or if you've got a live .iso extracted in a writable filesystem (some liveusb creators do that) copy them to a new dir. Or if going to burn to a cd/dvd could use a program to edit the iso & add files, or genisoimage.